# WSO2 api mgr mysql db

Tags: mysql, jdbc, wso2

i guess i'm not the only one trying to play with the new WSO2 API mgr.
As explained in readme, i try to use mysql to store all data.
I uploaded in the correct file the jdbc driver for mysql
now the question is to change the setting in master-datasources.xml but the only example provided is in the readme file but only for mssql and i also never used jdbc ...
using the mssql example in README what do you think of this setup customized for mysql :

```
    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:jtds:mysql://db.mydomain.com:3306/USERDB</url>
                <username>USER</username>
                <password>USER</password>
                <driverClassName>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

Comment: after googling a little i changed my setup but it can not connect to the db. the db is named wos2carbon and the userid/password with full right to access it had been created by hand...

Comment: it does not work and config file look like this now :

Answer (score 1):

In the posted datasource configuration, I see you are using JTDS driver to connect to MySQL which is wrong. JTDS only support MSSQL and Sybase databases and therefore you have to use the MySQL JDBC driver in order to get the datasource configured properly to connect to a MySQL backend database. To do that, Download the MySQL JDBC driver from [1] and place it inside API_MANAGER_HOME/repository/component/lib folder and change the datasource configuration as shown below.

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://hostname_or_ip:3306/database_name</url>
                <username>valid_mysql_username</username>
                <password>valid_mysql_password</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
```

Regards,
Prabath

[1] http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I've tried it just like this; well except I'm just changing the api manager datasource but I am getting an exception saying the jdbc driver isn't found.

I downloaded the driver from the link you provided, I untarred/gzipped it and put the .jar file  mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar in the repository/component/lib directory  - I also confired the jar file has the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class file.

Any tips?

Comment: Bill, can you double check whether the driver name is defined properly? (whether there are white spaces, etc in the driver name specified in your datasource configuration. You can also try putting the jar inside "repository/components/extensions" directory)

Comment: Prabath - that fixed the first problem but now I've got a second:

I ran ./wso2server.sh -Dsetup and things seem to load OK but when I try to save an API in the publisher I get an error "myschema.AM_API" doesn't exist.

I looked in mysql and the only tables that exist are prefixed with REG and UM (32 tables total).

Is there some step I'm missing to get the apimgt tables script to be executed?

Comment: Hi Bill, The problem you have faced is due to the API Manager mysql db script has not executed with the option -Dsetup.This is a bug as https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-13 and this will fix in future.For the moment,to overcome the issue,you can run that dbscript manually.You can find the related mysql db script from {AM_Home}/dbscripts/apimgt/mysql.sql and execute the script against your newly created mysql database.This will resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks lalaji that is what I ended up doing.    At the moment I think everything is good to go.

I do have a question though.  In evaulating setting things up in a distributed manner is there an advantage to having a separate datasource for the WSO2_CARBON_DB and the WSO2AM_DB?  Or is it better to have them both in the same schema?

Comment: Hi Bill, We have to define WSO2_CARBON_DB and WSO2AM_DB as two data-sources in master-datasources file.Because from code level we are referring each seperate data-sources to initialize and populate data .However you can point to same database from these two datasources or either keep two databases as one to store Carbon related data and other database to store API Manager related data.You can set your databases in above both way.The consideration with keeping separate database to each data-source is that if one database corrupted still you are having the other database data safe.

Comment: Having two separate databases is not only meant to avoid corruptions. For example, if you decide to have both database schemas installed on the same database using a enterprise level RDMBS such as MySQL, Oracle, etc then there's only a little possibility of getting the database corrupted. The other most significant reasons, as I see, to have those data in two separate databases is to have separation of concerns, ease of migration and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this page helped me: http://shavanthaw.blogspot.mx/2013/02/how-to-connect-wso2-is-server-to.html